# How can I change the read-only library to read&writable status in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, readonly

I am making an android project now.

I tried to use an external java library in my project, but I cannot access them.

The reason is that the library jar file is read-only status. I have searched a lot of stack overflow and applied the solutions, but it didn't solve my problem.

I tried to change manually the read-only status to r&w status by opening file's get info. It doesn't work.

Is there anyone who has experienced the same problem as me?

I attached the snapshot showing read-only files by locked folders & files.[image]

Comment: Tried unziping the jar and changing every file? Also if the original source code is not present than you must edit the bytecode directly, if it is you will need to recompile as jar, better to make a project of it then.

Comment: I also tried unziping the jar and changing every file. However, I didn't try your second solution. Thank you